# CLLocation region monitoring started but didExitRegion does not get called on iPhone

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I allow the user to set a location and then create a region and monitor if the user has exited or entered the region. I also constantly monitor the user's distance from the chosen location.
region monitoring is called, and the distances are correctly updated, but enter and exit are never called. This shows me going to 30 meters, but I've gone further with the same result.

```
-(void)setPlugLocation:(CLLocation *)plugLocation{
if (!_plugLocation) {
    _plugLocation=plugLocation;
    if(!regionManager) regionManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [regionManager setDelegate:self];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D plug2D;
    plug2D.latitude=plugLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    plug2D.longitude=plugLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    CLRegion *plugHome = [[CLRegion alloc] 
                            initCircularRegionWithCenter:plug2D 
                            radius:20 
                            identifier:@"Your Plug"];
    [regionManager startMonitoringForRegion:plugHome desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
}
}

debug output:
2012-05-25 21:28:29.921 TestLocation[4412:707]  locationManager didUpdateToLocation
2012-05-25 21:28:29.929 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=0.000000
2012-05-25 21:28:30.700 TestLocation[4412:707]  locationManager didUpdateToLocation
2012-05-25 21:28:30.704 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=9.897339
2012-05-25 21:28:33.106 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=15.923317
2012-05-25 21:28:34.783 TestLocation[4412:707] region monitoring started
(identifier Your Plug) <+47.61713686,-122.28694184> radius 20.00m
2012-05-25 21:28:34.784 TestLocation[4412:707] region monitoring started
(identifier Your Plug) <+47.61713686,-122.28694184> radius 20.00m
2012-05-25 21:28:34.788 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=19.705339
2012-05-25 21:28:56.894 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=12.808387
2012-05-25 21:28:57.894 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=12.808387
2012-05-25 21:29:05.893 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=12.808387
2012-05-25 21:29:19.890 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=12.808387
2012-05-25 21:30:02.892 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=14.614380
2012-05-25 21:30:32.893 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=14.614380
2012-05-25 21:30:52.891 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=15.352976
2012-05-25 21:32:41.898 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=7.644082
2012-05-25 21:32:43.891 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=12.354503
2012-05-25 21:32:49.068 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=15.757565
2012-05-25 21:32:52.984 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=21.126129
2012-05-25 21:32:56.880 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=26.952410
2012-05-25 21:33:04.925 TestLocation[4412:707] Distance from plug=31.824801
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing the correct region monitoring callback methods?

```
-didEnterRegion
-didExitRegion
```

A little info on the region monitoring. It isn't as precise as you would think. There is a minimum region size that will get added. The minimum size is 100M. So anything you add under 100M, will just get bumped up to 100M.

It looks like you are getting location updates in your output, so my guess is you just need to implement the CLLocationManagerDelegate methods to handle the region monitoring. You can also monitor to make sure the region is getting added correctly. It could be an error there which would lead to no callbacks.

```
-monitoringDidFailForRegion
```

Hope this helps.